# run a script using teamcity that require credentials

Tags: python, git, teamcity

I have a script that runs git remote commands and require user/password credential, because the script runs by teamcity I was wondering if there is a way for teamcity to pass these credential to my script?

Answer (score 2):

In my situation, I was trying to run a TeamCity Gradle "release" job.

I had several errors along the way, one of them being the original question to this post.

---

Here are the tools I am using:

- TeamCity (as my build machine, like Jenkins)
- Java application
- Gradle build
- Gradle release plug (id 'net.researchgate.release' version '2.6.0')
- Stash (for git version control)
- Nexus

---

**Problem 1:**
While trying to execute a build step, I was getting this error.  (Reminder, the build step is run after the VCS git checkout is complete)

```
[Step 5/5] Execution failed for task ':my-service:checkUpdateNeeded'. org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to run [git remote update] - [Fetching origin
][Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
error: Could not fetch origin
]
```

**Solution 1:**

- I am using an git via ssh (ssh://git@stash.somedomain.com/ins/my-service.git).
- I added an SSH key (for my git user) to TeamCity, which was successfully used for the git clone.
- This SSH key was added to Stash (Access keys) to allow for read/write access.
- When running the release job, it requires access to git again, to git fetch the latest code.
- In my case, I had to turn on the SSH-Agent (build feature).

What is happening is that TeamCity knows how to use the SSH key for VCS access.  But once the build steps start running, they dont know about the SSH keys, and thus the git authentication fails.

---

**Problem 2:**
After the "release" job does the git update, build, run tests, and build jars (artifacts) - the next step is for it to publish these jars to Nexus.

```
[Step 5/5] Execution failed for task ':my-service:my-service:myServiceCore:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository'. org.gradle.api.artifacts.PublishException: Failed to publish publication 'mavenJava' to repository 'maven'
[17:31:17][Step 5/5] Release process failed, reverting back any changes made by Release Plugin.
```

**Solution 2:**
I needed to add credentials to the build job, for write access to the Nexus `release` repos (not the `snapshot` repos).

- I added the `mavenUser` and `mavenPassword` as environment variables to the TeamCIty job.
- The `mavenPassword` is added as a `password format/spec`, so no one can see the value.
- Within my build step configuration, set the "Additional Gradle command line parameters:" `-DmavenUser=%env.mavenUser% -DmavenPassword=%env.mavenPassword%`
- In my build.gradle file, I use `System.getProperty("mavenUser")` to get access to these values
- In my build.gradle file, I added `println "Release Job - mavenUser=" + System.getProperty("mavenUser")`, so I could see if it was making into gradle.
- Look in Nexus to see your artifact (non-snapshot) made it, and check the timestamp

---

**Problem 3:**
Once the "release" job published the non-snapshot artifact to Nexus, it will update to a new version number (in `gradle.properties`).  It will commit/push this back to your git repo, on the `master` branch.

> ERROR: Branch refs/heads/master can only be modified through pull requests

```
[Step 5/5] Execution failed for task ':my-service:preTagCommit'. org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to push to remote - [To ssh://git@stash.somedomain.com/ins/my-service.git
!   refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master [remote rejected] (pre-receive hook declined)
][remote:                             *%%%%%.                                    
remote:                         %%%         %%%                                
remote:                      ,%#               %%                              
remote:                     %%                   %%                            
remote:                    %#                     %%                           
remote:                   %%                       %                           
remote:                   %(                       %%                          
remote:                   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                          
remote:                 %#%*%#///////%# %%///////%%%%%%                        
remote:                ,% %*%%******%#   %%******%(%%,%                        
remote:                  %%/ %%/**%%/%%%%%%%(**#%( %%#                         
remote:                   %%          %%%          %(                          
remote:                    %                      .%                           
remote:                    *%        %%%%%       .%                            
remote:                      %#                 %%                             
remote:                       .%%            .%%                               
remote:                       .%%.%%,     %%%.%%/                              
remote:                 %%%%%%##%.  #%%%%%.  .%((%%%%%%                        
remote:             %%#(((((((((%%,         #%%(((((((((#%%.                   
remote:       %%%((((((((((((((((((%%%, .%%%((((((((((((((((((#%%*             
remote:     %%(((((((((((((((((((((((((%(((((((((((((((((((((((((#%.           
remote:   ,%(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((%#          
remote:   %#((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((%          
remote:   %%%%%%%%%%%%%(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((%%%%%%%%%%%%%          
remote:  %%            %####((((((###%%%%%%%%#(((((((((%            ,%         
remote: ,%             %%%%%%#.               %%%((((((%*            %%        
remote: #%                                       %%%#                %%        
remote: .%                             .%%%%%%%%%                    %#        
remote:  %                         #%%%                              %         
remote:  %                     %%%%                                  %*        
remote: /%************/#%%%%%%######%%*                        ..,*/(%%        
remote:               %%######(((((((##################%%                      
remote:               %%######(((((((((((((((((((((((((%%                      
remote: //////////////%%%%%%%%#########################%%/////////  ///        
remote: ----------------------------------------------------        
remote: Branch refs/heads/master can only be modified through pull requests.        
remote: Check your branch permissions configuration with the project administrator.        
remote: ----------------------------------------------------        
remote: 
remote: 
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@stash.somedomain.com/ins/my-service.git'
]
```

**Solution 3:**
Make sure your git user (based on your SSH key) has access to update the git repo.

- In my case (in Stash) we do not allow "Changes without a pull request" to be merged into our "master" branch.
- Double check the git user (in Stash) has write access.
- Add your git user to the setting "Prevent changes without a pull request, except by:" (in Stash).

Run the "release" job again, and look in your git repo at the latest commits.

---

**Problem 4:**
It can take a long time for your build to run all tests, just to see if your release plugin will work.

**Solution 4:**
Add this TEMPORARILY to configure the "release" task (in build.gradle).

```
release {
    String skipTests = System.getProperty('skipTests', 'false')
    println "Release Job - skipTests=" + skipTests
    if (skipTests == 'true') {
            buildTasks = ['jar']
    }

    //Make sure the user/password is making it into Gradle
    println "Release Job - mavenUser=" + System.getProperty("mavenUser")
    println "Release Job - mavenPassword=" + System.getProperty("mavenPassword")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**TeamCity password parameter type**

Set the username and password as TC build parameters. Choose Edit on the Spec section, set the Type to `Password`. This will obfuscate the password in build logs and in all TC dialogs once you've set the param value.

Caveat to this, there's nothing stopping a wily user from adding a build step to `echo %my.fancy.secret.password%`. So your TC permissions will need to comply here.

**ssh**

As Mark said in his answer, ssh makes this a lot easier to manage with just about any build tool. We use [ssh_config](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) on our build agents, which your problem trivial.

Answer (score 0):

By design, TeamCity resists making usernames/passwords available to build steps. This is not to say that you couldn't make it work that way, but be aware of the reason it does it.  If anyone *should* be able to configure build jobs but *shouldn't* be able to see the password in question, you'd have a security problem.

The best solution in my opinion is to use SSH when possible.  TeamCity will be happy to run an ssh-agent while your build steps execute, configured with the private key (hence, the identity) of your choosing.  Just being able to configure a build does not give a user the ability to see the private key (or any other sensitive credential) in this scenario, even if they code cleverly and maliciously.

Of course this isn't *always* an option. But for basic git access it usually is, and you may want to consider it.